# Make Tor download only HTML

Tags: windows, proxy

I am using tor to play broswer games.
However, these games are heavy with visual content such as images and animations, and with Tor those are realy slow.
Is there a way to make Tor download plain HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible to download the HTML source code with right click on the link and "Save Link As...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: disabling images **will degrade your anonymity set**, possibly making you **unique**.

#### Disable images on a per-site basis

Right click somewhere on the page and click on <kbd>view page info</kbd>. Then switch to <kbd>permissions</kbd>, under the images section: uncheck the default and select block.

Unfortunately, unlike the global option below you cannot opt to only allow same-origin only images.

#### Disable images globally (load all images, no images, load same-origin only)

In `about:config` search for `permissions.default.image` and set it to 1, 2, or 3.

1. Load all images. (Default)
2. Load no images.
3. Load all but third party images.

Answer (score 1):

First,

If you mean download everything but images and animations, no, it's not possible. At least, not with the regular tor browser. You would have to make your own application where you would download the source code of the page and render it yourself using something like webkit. But that's a pain and you're probably better off without it.

Next, using tor to play games is not recommended at all. Most browser games use softwares like flash which can trick your computer to accidentally leak your actual IP. That makes the whole point of using tor useless.

[Check this link for best practices](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en)

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was to download only HTML, not everything but images and animations.

Comment: If you want just the HTML code to be downloaded, it's slightly complicated. If you're familiar with using the command prompt, there's a command called cURL. Configure that to work via TOR. Then, just type curl mywebsite.onion to download just the HTML code. This works for regular websites too